# MongoDB: $geoNear distances for elements in array

Tags: mongodb

Assuming collection like this:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc17f42532057004b487622"),
    "stops" : [ 
        {
            "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    106.8307333, 
                    -6.2174014
                ]
            },
            "timeOfArrival" : ISODate("2019-04-30T11:15:00.000Z"),
        }, 
        {
            "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    106.825769, 
                    -6.22772
                ]
            },
            "timeOfArrival" : ISODate("2019-04-30T11:22:00.000Z"),
        }, 
    ],
}]
```

Is it possible with single query to get distance for each stop?
I tried using `$geoNear` but I ended up with some general distance for whole document, not distance per each stop.

What I'd like to have is `distance` field in each stop, for instance stop in `stops` would look like this:

```
{
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            106.825769, 
            -6.22772
        ]
    },
    "timeOfArrival" : ISODate("2019-04-30T11:27:00.000Z"),
    "distance": 409.9942 // in meters
}
```

Comment: It actually cannot be done, or not with [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) anyway. MongoDB will happily find the *nearest* element from within an array inside a document and there is even the `includeLocs` option for that exact purpose ( which would allow you to identify the matching *nearest* array element ). However the problem is you cannot project a `distance` field for ALL array members. To do so you would need to `$unwind`, and you **cannot** do that since `$geoNear` **must** be the very first aggregation pipeline stage to use the index.

Comment: As for *"doing the math yourself"*, you cannot do that **yet**. However, [SERVER-32930](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32930) does include the math functions which would allow you to do this. OR you could possibly do this with `mapReduce` right now. But "brute force" calculations are probably not very efficient, and unless you actually need these "distances" for *further aggregation* then you are probably better off *"doing the math"* in client processing code instead.

Comment: Of course the other *"obvious"* option is where these "distances" for each "point" in the array are important  ( for aggregation or other usage ) then you are just better off storing in discreet documents, instead of using an array. The same general concept applies as to all other cases of *embedded arrays* in that if your **primary usage** is to work with the items *independently*, then they should be their own documents in a separate ( or even the same ) collection instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for these informations. I think you could move these locations to separate collection, in stops just use references and then I'll be probably be able to achieve my goal with some extra coding.

Comment: That was basically the gist of the last comment ( probably written only just before your own comment ). Probably could include as an "answer", but I *sort of feel* than an "answer" *should* demonstrate the coding approaches as well, and I honestly just don't have the time right now to write all that out. Maybe someone else will, or maybe I'll be able to come back to this later.